# SendMail to multiple contacts

Tags: sql-server-2008, sendmail

I know how to use this `SQL Server 2008` feature to send to 1 contant and bcc one contact, but how do I send to 3 contacts?

Would the syntax be like such?  This only sends the message to the 1st email address listed:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = 'DatabaseMail', 
  @recipients = '123@gmail.com';'456@gmail.com'
  @blind_copy_recipients = 'testasdf@gmail.com',
  @body_format = 'HTML',
  @from_address = 'Auto-Generated <AutoMailSenderSystem@rastafarianmenbraids.net>',
  @body = @tableHTML,
  @subject = @subject;
```

Comment: A list of addresses are normally separated by semi-colons ... ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

[ @recipients= ] 'recipients'

Is a **semicolon-delimited list of e-mail addresses** to send the message to. The recipients list is of type varchar(max). Although this parameter is optional, at least one of @recipients, @copy_recipients, or @blind_copy_recipients must be specified, or sp_send_dbmail returns an error.

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name = 'DatabaseMail', 
  @recipients = '123@gmail.com;456@gmail.com'
  @blind_copy_recipients = 'testasdf@gmail.com',
  @body_format = 'HTML',
  @from_address = 'Auto-Generated <AutoMailSenderSystem@rastafarianmenbraids.net>',
  @body = @tableHTML,
  @subject = @subject;
```